# bash: Use a variable to store stderr|stdout redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdout, brace-expansion

Is there any way to redirect stdout and stderr via variable like adding command options in script?

For example I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
TEST=">/dev/null 2>&1"
OPT='-p -v'
mkdir $OPT 123/123/123 $TEST
```

I can see that OPT is replaced with `-p` without any problems and bash interprets it as option. But redirection interprets as directories name.

```
$ ./test.sh 
+ TEST='>/dev/null 2>&1'
+ OPT='-p -v'
+ mkdir -p -v 123/123/123 '>/dev/null' '2>&1'
mkdir: created directory `123/123'
mkdir: created directory `123/123/123'
mkdir: created directory `>/dev'
mkdir: created directory `>/dev/null'
mkdir: created directory `2>&1'
```

Is there any way to say bash, that $VAR is redirection, not a dirs names.

PS. May be I'm on wrong way, but I want to make optional verbose or non verbose output from my script. But I need some output even in non-verbose mode, therefore I can't just redirect whole stdout and stderr, only from some commands inside of my script.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another solution could be the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

verbose=0

exec 3>&1
exec 4>&2

if ((verbose)); then
  echo "verbose=1"
else
  echo "verbose=0"
  exec 1>/dev/null
  exec 2>/dev/null
fi

echo "this should be seen if verbose"
echo "this should always be seen" 1>&3 2>&4
```

Then add `1>&3 2>&4` only to commands of which you want to see the output.

Comment: Great. This is exactly the thing I watched for. Thank you.

Comment: I have wrote [an article](https://transang.me/bash-redirection-explanation/) to explain how this works

Answer (score 7):

The "how" has been well explained in other answers; I want to address the "why" the OP's code doesn't work.

The keynote is that **output redirections are marked *before* variable expansion.**  Redirections are actually *performed* after variable expansion (hence why you can redirect output to a filename which is stored in a variable), but the shell *identifies* the redirections for later processing before variables are expanded.

In other words, once variables are expanded it is "too late" for a redirection character (`<` or `>`, etc.) to be considered, because the shell has already identified which parts of the command string it is going to handle as redirections.

For further reading, see steps 1 and 3 listed under:

```
LESS='+/^SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION' man bash
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not interpreting it as a "directory name", `>` is being quoted, so it being treated literally (more specifically, you are sending the string `>dev/null 2>&1`. Your only way of getting around this is using `eval` or spawning a new shell.

As for your "verbose" issue alluded to in your question, just do this instead:

```
verbose=1
if (( verbose )); then
    mkdir -v -p /foo
else
    mkdir -p /foo > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

enzotib's answer uses some good file descriptor magic, but a simpler solution would be to just use `eval` the line (which *does* add process overhead, however):

```
$ rm /tmp/foo
$ ll /tmp/foo
ls: cannot access /tmp/foo: No such file or directory
$ FOO=">/tmp/foo"
$ date $FOO
date: invalid date '>/tmp/foo'
$ cat /tmp/foo
cat: /tmp/foo: No such file or directory
$ eval date $FOO
$ cat /tmp/foo
Thu Dec 13 14:08:17 EST 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of spaces in your variables, which will not be evaluated properly. You will want to use `eval` to set that up.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
TEST=">/dev/null 2>&1"
OPT='-p -v'
eval mkdir $OPT 123/123/123 $TEST
```

This will allow $OPT to be split into two arguments (`-p` and `-v`) instead of one (`-p -v`) and the same with $TEST.  Also changed to use `/dev/null` since it is very unlikely that you will have a `dev` directory in the current directory.