# io redirection not working when command stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, variable

The following command lets me check if a webpage has specific content. It does not output anything unless the content is found.

```
curl -v --silent https://somedomain.com/somepage.html 2>&1 | grep 'some content'
```

The problem is, when I add this to a shell script, the output isn't suppressed any more.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST1="curl -v --silent https://somedomain.com/somepage.html 2>&1 | grep 'some content'"

$TEST1
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    #do something if exit status of last command not equal to zero
fi
```

I have the same problem if I try to store the output of the script in a variable (`VAL1`)

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST1="curl -v --silent https://somedomain.com/somepage.html 2>&1 | grep 'some content'"
VAL1+=$($TEST1)
echo "result should be blank or the found grep $VAL1"
```

Why does `2>&1` work as expected when running the command directly, but when   added to a script the output is directed in the command line?

**Update**

Jeffs hint's in the comments got me going in the right direction. The accepted answer is correct. The work around I did for my script was to move the code I originally tried to assign to a variable to be in a function and use `$( ... )`. This way everything ran as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash
# note that -z checks if variable is empty
test1() {
  VAL1=$(curl -v --silent https://somedomain.com/somepage.html 2>&1 | grep 'some content')
  if [[ -z $VAL1 ]]; then
    VAL1=test1fail
  fi
}

test1
echo $VAL1
```

Comment: pls show current output and expected output

Comment: It’s an interesting distinction, to me, given that redirection comes *after* parameter expansion in the sequence of operations.

Comment: Notice what happens under `set -x`: `curl ... '2>&1' ...` with the single-quotes around the redirection.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269259/117549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeff Schaller's comment [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269259/117549) is on the nose. The key message from the bash manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and **redirections** are **saved for later processing**.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are **expanded** (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)). If any words remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. **Redirections are performed** as described above (see [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)).
> 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

Step 1 identifies the redirections and saves them.
Step 2 is where variable expansion happens.

The shell sees no redirections in step 1.

Also relevant: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1):

The bad solution is to force a double evaluation :

```
eval "$TEST1"
```

The good solution is to split the command semantically (url, content) :

```
curl -v --silent "$url" |& grep "$content"
```

Note : `|&` is syntactic sugar for `2>&1 |`